# Where to place a directory of static files in Eclipse Dynamic Web Project

Tags: eclipse, jsp, static

I created a dynamic web project using Eclipse. I have a few java programs which I placed in the "Java Resources/src" folder. These programs use `Lucene` libraries which I placed in the "`WebContent/WEB-INF/lib`" folder. The Java programs need access to a few text files and a directory containing the index files generated by `Lucene`. I placed these static files under `WebContent` in eclipse so that they appear in the exported WAR file.

I am accessing these static files by referring to them directly in the Java program.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("abc.txt"));
```

> //abc.txt is in the WebContent folder of Eclipse project.

From the JSP page, I am calling the java program (which contains the above line) but it shows a `FileNotFoundException`. Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Place abc.txt file in the same folder where jsp file is located.

Answer (score 3):

You can not access resources available inside webapp directly from Java.

As files from `/src/YourClass.java` goes under `/WEB-INF/classes/` when compiled. So, When you try to access `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("abc.txt"));`.

It searches "abc.txt" at ``/WEB-INF/classes/abc.txt` as per your given example.

Use `servletContext.getRealPath("/");` which returns path of your web application's `webapps` directory  and then you can access resources using this path.

**Note:** The path returned by `servletContext.getRealPath("/");` also depends on how you have deployed web application. As by default eclipse used its own internal mechanism to deploy web application.

Here is the sample screenshot on how it should be[image: Tomcat- Web Application deploy Architecture]

**Servlet Code:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class StaticTestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ServletContext servletContext;
    private String rootPath;

    public StaticTestServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.init(config);
        servletContext = config.getServletContext();
        rootPath = servletContext.getRealPath("/");
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("In Get and my path: " + rootPath + "documents"); // documents is the direcotry name for static files
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("In Post and my path: " + rootPath + "documents"); // documents is the direcotry name for static files
    }
}
```