# How to access resources out of webcontent folder

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a dynamic Web Project in Eclipse and i am very new to this field. I want to place resource like CSS, PNGs out of webcontent folder in some source folder. But after that when I try to access it through a normal procedure I could not. Can anyone help me how to work with this kind of situation. Following is the project structure in case you need. [This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaNXR.png):

[image: 1]

Comment: please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506341/where-to-place-a-directory-of-static-files-in-eclipse-dynamic-web-project

Comment: Thank you, But that was not clear. Can you explain what you understood from that and how this relate to my problem??

Comment: The source folder contents get compiled/copied to a location that is not addressable by clients/web browsers, usually WEB-INF/classes. If you want to serve those CSS and image files to the browser, put them somewhere else under WebContent. Nothing in a source folder will be served to them.